# Mailboxer: cannot destroy object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer

I am trying to destroy an object within my ROR app.

But I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "mailboxer_conversation_opt_outs" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"mailboxer_conversation_o...
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"mailboxer_conversation_opt_outs"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum

    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `async_exec'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `block in exec_no_cache'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `log'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `exec_no_cache'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:584:in `execute_and_clear'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:160:in `exec_query'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:733:in `column_definitions'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:186:in `columns'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:43:in `columns'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:49:in `columns_hash'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:85:in `column_for'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:94:in `bind'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:103:in `last_chain_scope'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:139:in `add_constraints'
... 72 levels...
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:281:in `block in destroy'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:281:in `destroy'
    from (irb):5
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

I'm guessing this is related to this `mailboxer_conversation_opt_outs` table I don't have within my app.

I'm using Rails 4.2 and:

```
mailboxer (0.13.0)
  carrierwave (>= 0.5.8)
  foreigner (>= 0.9.1)
  rails (>= 3.2.0)
```

Is there a migration file I somehow missed?

Anyway, how come my object is connected to this table while the actual object cannot send messages?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try running `rake db:migrate`? Do you have `20131206080416_add_conversation_optout` in your `schema_migrations` table?

Comment: Nope. I'm guessing this migration has been added *after* I set up mailboxer at first (~3 years ago), right? How am I supposed to catch up on this?

Comment: Well I would look if that migration exists in your `schema_migrations` table. And on my local I would drop the db and re-create it and run the migrations again and see if that resolved it

Comment: The migration doesn't exists and my issue is happening in production so I can't afford dropping my database... If this is from a newer version, I guess there should be some upgrade steps that I missed or something?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a migration file I somehow missed?

Yes, see [itsnikolay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42089943/2518355) and the [`Upgrading`](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer#upgrading) section of the documentation.

> Anyway, how come my object is connected to this table while the actual object cannot send messages?

Your Model class is probably still calling the `acts_as_messageable` method, which includes the [`Mailboxer::Models::Messageable`](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer/blob/master/lib/mailboxer/models/messageable.rb) Module into your ActiveRecord class, which [declares several extra associations](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer/blob/master/lib/mailboxer/models/messageable.rb#L16-L17) on your model. If you don't care about upgrading Mailboxer and just want to disconnect your model from Mailboxer entirely, just delete the `acts_as_messageable` line and you should be able to destroy your records without any more failed association issues.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you use previous version of Mailboxer.

Try to migrate on new one:

```
$ rails generate mailboxer:namespacing_compatibility
$ rails generate mailboxer:install -s
$ rake db:migrate
```

Taken from documentation: https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer#upgrading